# Segfault on Server after Multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, server

So I'm trying to code a multi-threading server. I've spent an enormous time on the internet figuring out the correct way to do this and the answer as always seems to be it depends. Whenever I execute my code, the client successfully connects, and executes but when the thread terminates and returns to the while loop the whole program segfaults.

I probably could use a good spanking on a few other things as well such as my usage of global variables. The entirety of code is below, sorry for the inconsistent space/tabbing.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  This is a basic whiteboard server. You can query it, append to it and
  clear in it. It understands both encrypted and unencrypted data.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------- */

struct whiteboard {
    int line;
    char type;
    int bytes;
    char string[1024];
} *Server;

int serverSize, threadcount, id[5];
bool debug = true;
struct whiteboard *Server;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_t thread[5];

/* -------------------------------------------
  function: sigint_handler
  Opens a file "whiteboard.all" in writemode 
  and writes all white board information in 
  command mode.
 ------------------------------------------- */
void sigint_handler(int sig) 
{
    if (debug) printf("\nInduced SIGINT.\n");

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("whiteboard.all","w");

    int x=0;
    for (x;x<serverSize;x++) // Loop Responsible for iterating all the whiteboard entries.
    {
        if (debug) printf("@%d%c%d\n%s\n",Server[x].line,Server[x].type,Server[x].bytes,Server[x].string);
        fprintf(fp,"@%d%c%d\n%s\n",Server[x].line,Server[x].type,Server[x].bytes,Server[x].string);
    }

    if (debug) printf("All values stored.\n");

    free(Server); // Free dynamically allocated memory


    exit(1);

}

/* -------------------------------------------
  function: processMessage
  Parses '!' messages into their parts - 
  returns struct in response.
 ------------------------------------------- */
struct whiteboard processMessage(char * message)
{
    int lineNumber, numBytes;
    char stringType, entry[1028];

    if (debug) printf("Update Statement!\n");

    // Read line sent by Socket
    sscanf(message,"%*c%d%c%d\n%[^\n]s",&lineNumber,&stringType,&numBytes,entry);

    if (debug) printf("Processed: Line: %d, Text: %s\n",lineNumber,entry);

    // Parse information into local Struct
    struct whiteboard Server;
    Server.line = lineNumber;
    Server.type = stringType;
    Server.bytes = numBytes;
    strcpy(Server.string,entry);

    // If there is no bytes, give nothing
    if (numBytes == 0)
    {
        strcpy(Server.string,"");
    }

    return Server;
}


/* -------------------------------------------
  function: handleEverything
  Determines type of message recieved and 
  process and parses accordingly.
 ------------------------------------------- */
char * handleEverything(char* message, struct whiteboard *Server, char* newMessage)
{
    bool updateFlag = false, queryFlag = false;

    // If message is an Entry
    if (message[0] == '@')
    {
        if (debug) printf("Triggered Entry!\n");

        // Create Temporary Struct
        struct whiteboard messageReturn;
        messageReturn = processMessage(message);

        // Store Temporary Struct in Correct Heap Struct
        Server[messageReturn.line] = messageReturn;
        sprintf(newMessage,"!%d%c%d\n%s\n",messageReturn.line, messageReturn.type, messageReturn.bytes, messageReturn.string);
        return newMessage;
    }

    // If message is a query
    if (message[0] == '?')
    {
        if (debug) printf("Triggered Query!\n");

        int x;
        queryFlag = true;

        sscanf(message,"%*c%d",&x); // Parse Query

        if (x > serverSize) // Check if Query out of Range
        {
            strcpy(newMessage,"ERROR: Query out of Range.\n");
            return newMessage;
        }   

        sprintf(newMessage,"!%d%c%d\n%s\n",Server[x].line,Server[x].type,Server[x].bytes,Server[x].string);

        if (debug) printf("newMessage as of handleEverything:%s\n",newMessage);
        return newMessage;
    }   
}

/* -------------------------------------------
  function: readFile
  If argument -f given, read file
  process and parse into heap memory.
 ------------------------------------------- */
void readFile(char * filename)
{

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");

    int line, bytes, count = 0, totalSize = 0;
    char type, check, string[1028], individualLine[1028];


    // Loop to determine size of file. **I know this is sloppy.
    while (fgets(individualLine, sizeof(individualLine), fp)) 
    {
        totalSize++;
    }

    // Each line shoud have totalSize - 2 (to account for 0)
    // (answer) / 2 to account for string line and instruction.
    totalSize = (totalSize - 2) / 2;
    serverSize = totalSize+1;
    if (debug) printf("Total Size is: %d\n",serverSize);

    // Open and Allocate Memory
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    if (debug) printf("File Mode Calloc Initialize\n");
    Server = calloc(serverSize+2, sizeof(*Server));

    // Write to Heap Loop
    while (fgets(individualLine, sizeof(individualLine), fp)) {
        if (individualLine[0] == '@') // Case of Header Line
        {               
            sscanf(individualLine,"%c%d%c%d",&check,&line,&type,&bytes);
            if (debug) printf("Count: %d, Check:%c, Line:%d, Type: %c, Bytes:%d \n",count,check,line,type,bytes);

            Server[count].line = line;
            Server[count].type = type;
            Server[count].bytes = bytes;
            count++;    
        }

        else
        {
            // For case of no data
            if (individualLine[0] == '\n')
            {
                strcpy(string,"");
            }

            // Then scan data line
            sscanf(individualLine,"%[^\n]s",string);        
            if (debug) printf("String: %s\n",string);           
            strcpy(Server[count-1].string,string);
        }
    }
    return;
}


void *threadFunction(int snew)
{
    char tempmessage[1024], message[2048];
    // Compile and Send Server Message
    strcpy(tempmessage, "CMPUT379 Whiteboard Server v0\n");
    send(snew, tempmessage, sizeof(tempmessage), 0);

    // Recieve Message
    char n = recv(snew, message, sizeof(message), 0);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    if (debug) printf("Attempt to Malloc for newMessage\n");
    char * newMessage = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));

    if (debug) printf("goto: handleEverything\n");
    newMessage = handleEverything(message, Server, newMessage);
    if (debug) printf("returnMessage:%s\n",newMessage);

    strcpy(message,newMessage); 
    free(newMessage);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    if (debug) printf("message = %s\n", message);

    send(snew, message, sizeof(message), 0);
    printf("End of threadFunction\n");

   return;
}



/* -------------------------------------------
  function: main
  Function Body of Server
 ------------------------------------------- */
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int sock, fromlength, outnum, i, socketNumber, snew;
  bool cleanMode;

  // Initialize Signal Handling
  struct sigaction act;
  act.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0);

  // For correct number of arguments.
  if (argc == 4)
  {
    // If "-n" parameter (cleanMode)
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-n") == 0)
    {
        // Get size + 1
        cleanMode = true;
        sscanf(argv[3],"%d",&serverSize);
        serverSize += 1;

        if (debug) printf("== Clean Mode Properly Initiated == \n");
        if (debug) printf("serverSize: %d\n",serverSize);

        if (debug) printf("Clean Mode Calloc\n");
        Server = calloc(serverSize, sizeof(*Server));

        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < serverSize; i++) // Initialize allocated Memory
        {
            Server[i].line = i;
            Server[i].type = 'p';
            Server[i].bytes = 0;
            strcpy(Server[i].string,"");
        }
    }

    // If "-f" parameter (filemode)
    else if (strcmp(argv[2], "-f") == 0)
    {
        // Read File
        cleanMode = false;
        readFile(argv[3]);

        if (debug) printf("== Statefile Mode Properly Initiated == \n");
        if (debug) printf("serverSize: %d\n",serverSize);
    }

    // Otherwise incorrect parameter.
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect Argument. \n");
        printf("Usage: wbs279 pornumber {-n number | -f statefile}\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&socketNumber);
  }

  // Send Error for Incorrect Number of Arguments
  if (argc != 4)
  {
    printf("Error: Incorrect Number of Input Arguments.\n");
    printf("Usage: wbs279 portnumber {-n number | -f statefile}\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // == Do socket stuff ==

  char tempmessage[1024], message[2048];
  struct sockaddr_in master, from;

  if (debug) printf("Assrt Socket\n");

  sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0) 
  {
    perror ("Server: cannot open master socket");
    exit (1);
  }

  master.sin_family = AF_INET;
  master.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  master.sin_port = htons (socketNumber);

  if (bind (sock, (struct sockaddr*) &master, sizeof (master))) 
  {
    perror ("Server: cannot bind master socket");
    exit (1);
  }

  // == Done socket stuff == 

  listen (sock, 5);
  int threadNumber = 0;

  while(1) 
  {
    printf("But what about now.\n");
    if (debug) printf("-- Wait for Input --\n");
    printf("Enie, ");
    fromlength = sizeof (from);
    printf("Meanie, ");
    snew = accept (sock, (struct sockaddr*) & from, & fromlength);
    printf("Miney, ");  
    if (snew < 0) 
    {
      perror ("Server: accept failed");
      exit (1);
    }
    printf("Moe\n");


    pthread_create(&thread[threadNumber],NULL,threadFunction(snew), &id[threadNumber]);
    //printf("Can I join?!\n");
    //pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);
    //printf("Joined?!\n");

    threadNumber++;

    close (snew);
  }
}
```

I'm also curious as to how exactly to let multiple clients use the server at once. Is how I've allocated the whiteboard structure data appropriate for this process?

I'm very sorry if these don't make any sense.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that opening a new thread per connection is a bad idea. Multi-threaded servers often use a thread pool rather than a thread-per-client, since context-switching can become expensive when opening too many threads (it's easier to experience DoS when using a thread-per-client design)... you can read through [facil.io](http://facil.io) as an example for my proposed approach.

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )   Using these parameters to `gcc`, the posted code produces 25 warnings, several of which are very serious. (so perhaps also use: `-Werror` )

Answer (score 1):

You seem to somehow expect this:

```
pthread_create(&thread[threadNumber],NULL,threadFunction(snew), &id[threadNumber]);
/* ... */
close (snew);
```

To make sense, while it clearly doesn't.

Instead of starting a thread that runs `threadFunction`, passing it `snew`, you *call* the thread function and pass the return value to `pthread_create()`, which will interpret it as a function pointer. This will break, especially considering that the thread function incorrectly ends with:

```
return;
```

This shouldn't compile, since it's declared to return `void *`.

Also assuming you managed to start the thread, passing it `snew` to use as its socket: then you immediately close that socket, causing any reference to it from the thread to be invalid!

Please note that `pthread_create()` does not block and wait for the thread to exit, that would be kind of ... pointless. It starts off the new thread to run in parallel with the main thread, so of course you can't yank the carpet away from under it.

Comment: I appreciate it. I kinda thought A LOT was up. How do I correctly start a thread the runs threadFunction rather than simply calling it?

Comment: The call is done by the `()`, so just give the name of the function (which evaluates to a function pointer, when needed). Something like `pthread_create(&thread[threadNumber], NULL, threadFunction, (void *) snew);`. This passes `snew` as the thread's argument. If you can't figure this out from e.g. [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html), I think you need to study some more. :)

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: usually better to separate a struct definition from the declaration of an instance of that struct.

Comment: there are only a very few system functions that are 'safe' to use in a signal handler function.  `fprintf()` and `printf()` are not amongst them

Comment: function: `processMessage()` is returning a struct rather than a pointer to a struct.  If the struct is larger than a couple of CPU registers, then problems arise.  Strongly suggest calling `malloc()` to get memory for the struct then returning a pointer to that memory

Comment: regarding this format string: `"%*c%d%c%d\n%[^\n]s"` the final `s` (unless every message will end in a superficial `s`,) should not be part of the format string.

Comment: the call to `sscanf()` will always place (at least) a NUL byte into the `entry[]` array, so this statement: `strcpy(Server.string,entry);` will always work,  so the code block beginning with: `if (numBytes == 0)` does nothing and should be removed

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with to basis.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, Then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the variable `*Server` is defined in two places,  Both places are in the file global name space.  once at line 25 and again at line 29

Comment: What happens when `totalSize` is < 2?  Note: `totalSize` is the number of lines in the file, not the total length of any/all lines

Comment: function: `readFile()` opens the same file twice, for the same mode, in the same file pointer, with out an intermediate call to `fclose()`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this line: `sscanf(individualLine,"%[^\n]s",string);` the trailing `s` in the format string should not be there.  the `[^\n]` will not read the newline so that would be next in the input, not a `s`  So, most likely the call to `sscanf()` will fail.  Suggest removing that trailing `s` from the format string.

Comment: this line: `void *threadFunction(int snew)` should be: `void *threadFunction( void* data)` Note: correct the call to `pthread_create()` also.  and the first line in the body of the function should be: `int snew = (int)*data;

Comment: when declaring a mutex, it needs to be initialized,  use either `pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`  -or-

`pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_mutex_init ( &lock, NULL);`

Comment: when calling `send()` or `recv()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when exiting a pthread function, use: `pthread_exit( &status );`  where `status` is an integer that contains the return status from the function

Comment: when the incorrect number of command line parameters was entered by the user, out a USAGE message to stderr, not stdout, that indicates how the program should have been invoked.   This is usually a statement similar to `fprintf( stdere, "USAGE: %s .,... \n", argv[0] );`

Comment: this code sequence: `snew = accept (sock, (struct sockaddr*) & from, & fromlength);
    printf("Miney, ");
    if (snew < 0)
    {
      perror ("Server: accept failed");
      exit (1);
    }` will not work correctly when an error occurs, because the interviening call to `printf()` will have changed the value of `errno` and `perror()` outputs its' message depending on the value of `errno`

Answer (score 1):

This signal handler is completely unsafe:

```
void sigint_handler(int sig) 
{
    if (debug) printf("\nInduced SIGINT.\n");

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("whiteboard.all","w");

    int x=0;
    for (x;x<serverSize;x++) // Loop Responsible for iterating all the whiteboard entries.
    {
        if (debug) printf("@%d%c%d\n%s\n",Server[x].line,Server[x].type,Server[x].bytes,Server[x].string);
        fprintf(fp,"@%d%c%d\n%s\n",Server[x].line,Server[x].type,Server[x].bytes,Server[x].string);
    }

    if (debug) printf("All values stored.\n");

    free(Server); // Free dynamically allocated memory


    exit(1);

}
```

[Per **2.4.3 Signal Actions** of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) (emphasis added):

> The following table defines a set of functions that shall be
> async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can call them, without
> restriction, from signal-catching functions. ...
>
> [list of async-signal-safe functions]
>
> **Any function not in the above table may be unsafe with respect to signals.** Implementations may make other interfaces
> async-signal-safe. In the presence of signals, all functions defined
> by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall behave as defined when called
> from or interrupted by a signal-catching function, with the exception
> that **when a signal interrupts an unsafe function or equivalent**
> (such as the processing equivalent to exit() performed after a return
> from the initial call to main()) **and the signal-catching function
> calls an unsafe function, the behavior is undefined.** Additional
> exceptions are specified in the descriptions of individual functions
> such as longjmp().

Your signal handler invokes undefined behavior.